# HashMap - not returning correct value for equal keys

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm playing around with HashMaps in Java and I've stumbled upon something that I can't make sense of. I can't seem to find a duplicate of my issue on here either.

I'm trying to create a Map that has a `VertexPair` key and an `Integer` value. The `VertexPair` is simply a container for 2 `Vertex` objects. When I create 2 `VertexPairs` that have the same hash code and are equal (verified by .equals()), they do not return the same value from my map.

Here is my code:

```
HashMap<VertexPair, Integer> edges = new HashMap<VertexPair, Integer>();

Vertex a = new Vertex("A");
Vertex b = new Vertex("B");

VertexPair p = new VertexPair(a, b);
VertexPair m = new VertexPair(a, b);
VertexPair n = new VertexPair(b, a);
VertexPair check = new VertexPair(a, new Vertex("C"));

System.out.println(p.equals(m));
System.out.println(p.equals(n));
System.out.println(m.equals(n));
//just to be sure equals is working
System.out.println(p.equals(check));

System.out.println(m.hashCode());
System.out.println(n.hashCode());
System.out.println(p.hashCode());
//just to be sure hashCode is working
System.out.println(check.hashCode());

edges.put(p, 10);

System.out.println(edges.get(p));
System.out.println(edges.get(m));
System.out.println(edges.get(n));
```

And it's output:

```
true
true
true
false
1757285723
1757285723
1757285723
-425440240
10
null
null
```

Here is the VertexPair class as requested:

```
public final class VertexPair {

    private HashSet<Vertex> set;

    public VertexPair(Vertex a, Vertex b) {
        if(a==null || b==null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Vertexes must not be null");
        set = new HashSet<Vertex>();
        set.add(a);
        set.add(b);
    }

    public HashSet<Vertex> getVertexes() {
        return set;
    }       

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return set.hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(VertexPair p) {
        if(!(p instanceof VertexPair))
            return false;
        if(p==this)
            return true;
        return set.equals(p.getVertexes());

    }


}
```

Can someone please explain to me what's going on? I must be misunderstanding something crucial about HashMaps. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
public boolean equals(VertexPair p) {
```

with

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object p) {
```